# Trying to understand pandas.DataFrame.mode() output shape

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compute the mode along the rows of specific columns of a pandas DataFrame.

I have no problems in following the on-line examples. The following code works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import platform
import sys
    
print('python', platform.python_version())
print('numpy', np.__version__)
print('pandas', pd.__version__)

data = [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
        [1, 0, 0, 0, -1], 
        [1, -1, np.nan, 0, +1], 
        [-1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, -1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'], 
                  index=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'])
print(df)

df['mode'] = df.mode(axis='columns')
print(df['mode'])
    
# restrict mode() to columns: a1, a2
df['mode'] = df[['a1', 'a2']].mode(axis='columns', dropna=True)
print(df['mode'])
```

whose output is:

```
python 3.8.5 
numpy 1.19.4 
pandas 1.2.0

    a1   a2   a3   a4   a5 
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 
1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0 
2  1.0 -1.0  NaN  0.0  1.0 
3 -1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN -1.0

0    NaN
1    0.0
2    1.0
3   -1.0
Name: mode, dtype: float64

0    NaN
1    0.0
2   -1.0
3   -1.0
Name: mode, dtype: float64
```

However, when I load my tsv file, it does not work as above.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('annotation.tsv', sep='\t')
print(df2[['ann_1', 'ann_2']])

     ann_1  ann_2
0      NaN    NaN
1      NaN   -1.0
2      NaN    NaN
3      NaN    1.0
4      NaN    NaN
..     ...    ...
162    NaN    1.0
163    1.0    1.0
164    1.0    1.0
165    NaN   -1.0
166    1.0    1.0

[167 rows x 2 columns]

A = df2[['ann_1', 'ann_2']].mode(axis='columns')

print(type(A))
print(A.shape)
print(A)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(167, 2)
       0   1
0    NaN NaN
1   -1.0 NaN
2    NaN NaN
3    1.0 NaN
4    NaN NaN
..   ...  ..
162  1.0 NaN
163  1.0 NaN
164  1.0 NaN
165 -1.0 NaN
166  1.0 NaN

[167 rows x 2 columns]
```

*My question is: why does mode() produce two columns in the second case?*

Answer (score 1):

Reason is because there are same number of maximal number of values, so pandas return all modes.

```
#chnaged data
data = [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
        [1, 1, 0, 0, -1], 
        [1, -1, np.nan, 1, -1], 
        [-1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, -1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'], 
                  index=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'])
print(df)
     a1   a2   a3   a4   a5
f1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
f2  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0 <- 2 times 0, 2 times 1
f3  1.0 -1.0  NaN  1.0 -1.0 <- 2 times -1, 2 times 1
f4 -1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN -1.0

print(df.mode(axis='columns'))
      0    1
f1  NaN  NaN
f2  0.0  1.0 <- 2 times 0, 2 times 1
f3 -1.0  1.0 <- 2 times -1, 2 times 1
f4 -1.0  NaN
```

Possible solution is select first column:

```
print(df.mode(axis='columns').iloc[:, 0])
f1    NaN
f2    0.0
f3   -1.0
f4   -1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64


df['mode'] = df.mode(axis='columns').iloc[:, 0]
print(df)
     a1   a2   a3   a4   a5  mode
f1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
f2  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0   0.0
f3  1.0 -1.0  NaN  1.0 -1.0  -1.0
f4 -1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN -1.0  -1.0
```